# Compass Android 2.3 Support

Tags: android, css, sass, compass-sass, android-2.3-gingerbread

I'm using Compass 1.0.19 beta with the following browser support definition:

```
$support-for-original-webkit-gradients : true !default;

$browser-minimum-versions:  (ie:'8', chrome: null, firefox: null, opera: null, safari: null);
```

Problem is I have a linear gradient definition which is not generating the appropriate syntax for Android 2.3:

```
@include background-image(linear-gradient(white, black));
```

Any idea of what I'm missing?